# Configure lighttpd to different hosts for different client IPs

Tags: lighttpd

I have a server running lighttp. For testing purposes I would like to use a different host for a request if it originates from a specific IP. For example:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)example\.com$" {
    #### for live system
    server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/http"

    #### for requests from ip xxx
    server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/testing/http"
    …
}
```

Is this achievable with the use of config modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$HTTP["remoteip"]` for this check:

> `$HTTP["remoteip"]` match on the remote IP or a remote Network (Warning: doesn't work with IPv6 enabled)

Then your config file:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)example\.com$" {
    #### for live system
    $HTTP["remoteip"] == "10.10.10.10" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/http"
    }

    #### for requests from ip xxx
    $HTTP["remoteip"] == "11.11.11.11" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/testing/http"
    }
}
```

You also can use an `else`:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)example\.com$" {
    #### for requests from ip xxx
    $HTTP["remoteip"] == "11.11.11.11" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/testing/http"
    }
    #### for live system
    else {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/http"
    }
}
```